# How to keep from each parent only children by id from object

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I am trying to keep only children from each parent if it matches a child's id from a given list of parent/child ids.

```
var parentIds = ['1','2','3']; 
var childrenIds = ['2','3','5'];
```

**Parent with id '1'** should only have **children with id '2'**, **parent with id '2'** should only have **children with id '3'** and **parent with id '3'** should only have **children with id '5'**. So, parent id matches children id in same position from both arrays.

Example of initial object:

```
var object = [
  {
    name: "parent1",
    id: 1,
    option_values: [
      {
        name: "child1",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "child2",
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: "child8",
        id: 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent2",
    id: 2,
    option_values: [
      {
        name: "child3",
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: "child1",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "child9",
        id: 9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent3",
    id: 3,
    option_values: [
      {
        name: "child5",
        id: 5
      },
      {
        name: "child4",
        id: 4
      },
      {
        name: "child13",
        id: 13
      }
    ]
 },
 ]
```

Expected result:

```
var result = [
  {
    name: "parent1",
    id: 1,
    option_values: [
      {
        name: "child2",
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent2",
    id: 2,
    option_values: [
      {
        name: "child3",
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent3",
    id: 3,
    option_values: [
      {
        name: "child5",
        id: 5
      }
    ]
 },
 ]
```

Comment: I do not understand. you have been a member for 8 years and you post a question without showing what you have tried to achieve. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the objects. Find the index of the parent ID in the `parentIds` array, then get the corresponding element of childIds. Then filter the `option_values` array using that child ID.

```js
var object = [{
    name: "parent1",
    id: 1,
    option_values: [{
        name: "child1",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "child2",
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: "child8",
        id: 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent2",
    id: 2,
    option_values: [{
        name: "child3",
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: "child1",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "child9",
        id: 9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "parent3",
    id: 3,
    option_values: [{
        name: "child5",
        id: 5
      },
      {
        name: "child4",
        id: 4
      },
      {
        name: "child13",
        id: 13
      }
    ]
  },
];

var parentIds = ['1', '2', '3'];
var childrenIds = ['2', '3', '5'];

object.forEach(obj => {
  let idIndex = parentIds.indexOf(String(obj.id));
  if (idIndex != -1) {
    let childId = parseInt(childrenIds[idIndex]);
    obj.option_values = obj.option_values.filter(child => child.id == childId);
  }
});

console.log(object);
```